# Disabling power management

Tags: x11, power-management, profile, screensaver

I am running Cubieez on a Cubieboard2, I need to disable screen saver and power management, I've followed several tutorials about but none seems to work, I've written:

```
xset s off.
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
exec /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager
```

In `~/.xinitrc` but the board keeps going to blank. What's more interesting is that if I enter `xset -dpms` in the command line it works and stops the power management, so I wonder is if it really reading the `~/.xinitrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are starting your graphical environment using `startx` or `xinit`, `~/.xinitrc` is not being read. You should add the lines to your `~/.profile` instead.

To make sure they are only run when you have an active X session, use:

```
if [ ! -t 0 ]; then
    set s off.
    xset -dpms
    xset s noblank
    exec /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager
fi
```

Comment: wierd, i did what you said, .profile is in /root, i wrote what you said but monitor goes to blank anyway, any other idea on what can be happenig?